# Finding the most repeated integer without Maps

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have an arraylist of integers from a file that goes as follows. 1,3,4,3,5,6,5,5 I have already sorted the integers but as you can see there are integers that repeat. I would like to know how do I find the integer that is repeated the most then print it out?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;



public class Lab8
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {

     ArrayList<Integer>myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     Scanner myFile = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
     while (myFile.hasNextInt())
     {
       myInts.add(myFile.nextInt());

     }
     System.out.println(myInts);
     Collections.sort(myInts);
       System.out.println(myInts);
   }
}
```

Comment: My idea is by writing some code and sharing it here.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. My code is now up there.

Comment: Can you also show how you've attempted to solve the problem so far, and indicate what trouble you're having with your current solution? The problem is, the way the question is written thus far, any answer would essentially be doing your work done for you, and we'd be robbing you of the chance to learn yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    int max = 0;
    int nextMax = 0;
    int maxItem = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myInts.size(); i++) {
        if(i == 0 )
            continue;
        if(myInts.get(i) == myInts.get(i-1)) {
            if(max > nextMax ) {
                nextMax = max;
                maxItem = myInts.get(i);
            }
            else {
                max++;
                nextMax = max;
                maxItem = myInts.get(i);
            }
        } else {
            max = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxItem);
```